# ASP.net core IQueryableUserStore how to implement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Can someone explain to me how I can implement `IQueryableUserStore` in my `UserStore`?

This is my `UserStore`:

```
 public class UserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserPhoneNumberStore<ApplicationUser>,
    IUserTwoFactorStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserRoleStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserCustom<ApplicationUser>, IQueryableUserStore<ApplicationUser>
{ 
     ...
     public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> Users => throw new NotImplementedException();
     ...
}
```

My goal is to have the ability to have a method to retrieve my `ApplicationUser` custom field; if I try to use this command

```
 (_userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault().MyCustomField)`
```

I've got an error about

> IQueryableUserStore not implemented.

Comment: did you let visual studio/code complete the interface requirements in your class?

Comment: VS implement this "public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> Users => throw new NotImplementedException();"

Comment: right, but that throws not implemented...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
```